# Loss Fluctuation in YOLOv4

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, darknet

**Anyone knows why Loss values have considerably more fluctuation at YOLOv4 than YOLOv3?**

[image: o]

[image]

[image: o]

Comment: I have a same issue, did you find the reason for this?

Comment: Long time ago. Dont really remember

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many differences that exist between yolov3 and yolov4 is the data augmentation process.

Check if in v4 you used mosaic and/or random. Anyway, look deeply into yours cfg.